# Межпроцессный обмен данными

Tags: c++, c, vba

Создать комплект из3-х совместно работающих исполняыемых модулей (.exe)
a.exe- нахождение максимума из заданной последовательности чисел
 нахождение минимуму из заданой последовательности числе 
управляющей программы, обеспечивающей вывод и проверку корректности ввода и вызов соответствующей A ИЛИ B
Как написать составные части я знаю  а вот как 3 программы одновременно запустить нет

Comment: *как 3 программы одновременно запустить* Одновременно - никак. Последовательно, запуская следующую, не ожидая завершения предыдущей - запросто.

Comment: Как,? Там на выбор надо тип, 3 программа управляющая, она спрашивает запустить А или В ,

Comment: Можно ожидание на семафор в 3х частях сделать и разом все 3 запустить по нему.